# Unable to validate signature with unicode characters

Tags: java, base64

I am trying to validate a signature by providing a string and also the signature created by a different code. When validating, it works fine when the string doesn't contain unicode characters but fails when it has unicode characters. Need some help on how to solve this problem.

Snippet1 - Creating the signature

```
public static String sign(String plainText, PrivateKey privateKey) throws Exception {
        Signature privateSignature = Signature.getInstance(Constants.SHA256WITH_RSA);
        privateSignature.initSign(privateKey);
        privateSignature.update(plainText.getBytes(Constants.UTF_8));
        System.out.println("Payload before Encoding::"+plainText);
        byte[] signature = privateSignature.sign();

        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(signature);
    }
```

Snippet2- Validator

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const fs = require('fs');

const getSignatureVerifyResult = () => {

  const signatureText = `cnPiCPt0Wh8c/QLz38CJlk3pNdTHP9TVVrBlEwtkpmRZ8Csmis/uTdu57wi+Ldsm/IExzJa+lue61JoKhE1rYpcmD2FzXkNJlwskkOL1m9LAfu9nkuTgUjoBmAFaOwmHJWwyQyB3UhW53HFhHj26oE1iRNLBMKRW/9anltzmIMy2KNmvWHrDfKwDLTiEBBjEgbv6byB68u16svm3wcu9J1yMQ6qJkGyOP5+KczTnyzEUg76C9zUAoAyNzIjTUKNxKpJWUweUzngU7vvLpsavupPapQjgqkLjSaUiFPQdZR2Do7HggeVPiccSZG148qLv10ndvzm3nR5KZh8/BPnENg==`
  const input = `{"data":{"message":{"message_parts":[{"text":{"content":"\u003e"}}]}}}`

  const publicKeyStr = fs.readFileSync('public_key.txt', { encoding : 'utf8' })

  const verifier = crypto.createVerify('RSA-SHA256')
  verifier.update(input)

  const publicKeyBuf = Buffer.from(publicKeyStr, 'utf-8')
  const signatureBuf = Buffer.from(signatureText, 'base64')
  const result = verifier.verify(publicKeyBuf, signatureBuf)

  return result

}

console.log(getSignatureVerifyResult());
```

Comment: Did you try to validate the unicode message on the same system (Java) ?